# Joomla PHP file location

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

Let’s presume you have a page that is created dynamically by the Joomla core framework or a Joomla component. On this page – when viewed in your browser of choice, you wish to edit the PHP wireframe template file and add additional PHP code to improve the page view.

If you do not know the specific PHP file used to create the page you are viewing, what Chrome, Firefox or code explorer tools could you use to figure out the associated PHP file while you are browsing? Chrome and Firefox web developer tools show the associated HTML and CSS files.

Comment: A Joomla page doesn't exist as a separate file anywhere. Based on data in the URL, Joomla loads the appropriate content from the database and wraps it in your site's template. See http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/adding-custom-css-styling-on-some-of-my-pages for how to style them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has an answer on the Joomla SE (http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/adding-custom-css-styling-on-some-of-my-pages).

Comment: Please dont close yet.  Im sorry if its already explained but I would like to have this up as reference.

Comment: Closing doesn't remove it "as reference", and the question I linked to serves as a much better reference anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you can not give the php file address that are view on an html page. because php on view is convert to html file.
just a way is available to get the address of your file.
you can download all source of script and search it with notepad++ for html tags that are show on html viewed page.
good luck